# Invalid Column Name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Verán el código insertado mas abajo esta diseñado para eliminar un nombre de una base de datos, entonces me empezaba a marcar error de exepcion "Invalid Column Name", fue cuando use el try/catch pero cuando ejecuto la secuencia solo arroja el message box del catch, espero su apoyo

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        String reaction = txtUsser.Text;
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && eliminar.Checked==true)
        {
            string q = "delete from Usser where Nombre=" + reaction;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Trabajador eliminado de la base de datos exitosamente");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error inesperado, verifique los datos ingresados", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inténtalo de esta manera:

```
string q = "delete from Usser where Nombre='" + reaction + "'";
```

Ten en cuenta que estás comparando una variable de tipo `string`.

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaracion me fue muy util

Comment: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        String reaction = txtUsser.Text;
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && eliminar.Checked==true)
        {
            string q = "delete from Usser where Nombre='"+ reaction+"'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Trabajador eliminado de la base de datos exitosamente");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error inesperado, verifique los datos ingresados", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
    }
```

El error es por que los campos NVARCHAR/VARCHAR en SQL se ponen con '' entonces deberías mandar delete where fiel='algo' y tu estas mandando delete where field=algo

*Nota te recomiendo cambiar el modo en el que lo haces.

Por temas de seguridad

> Modo seguro para evitar inyección de SQL

```
 string q = "delete from Usser where Nombre=@Nombre";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(q, connection);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@Nombre"].Value = reaction;

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("RowsAffected: " + rowsAffected.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    }
               }
```

Comment: tienes razón debería enviar los parámetros con **@**

Comment: Aun no aprendo esa sintaxis de progamacion

Comment: Intenta como lo estas haciendo y si funciona puedes marcar la respuesa como correcta y de paso te muestro el otro modo.

Comment: una vez que termine mi proyecto estudiare ese formato a fondo gracias